# Hololens 2 - Deployed scene understanding sample app from Microsofts, no virtual representation of the real environment is seen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I read through the [scene understanding SDK overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/scene-understanding-sdk) by Microsoft and was trying to deploy its [sample app](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples). I followed through the instructions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples), and everything got built and deployed successfully to my Hololens2. However, when I was trying out the application on my Hololens2, there is 1 major problem: The menu doesn't render smoothly, it seems to be continuously covered by black blocks. Neither does the virtual representation renders smoothly, everything seems to lag. It should be looking [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jGHA.png) from Microsoft's documentation.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090385/hololens-2-microsoft-has-anyone-gotten-scene-understanding-to-work-in-realti) but not sure if the problem is similar. May I ask if anyone has successfully used the scene understanding sample app and has any idea what caused the issue?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your test environment so that we can reproduce your issue? Such as your HoloLens OS version and Unity Version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have followed these steps to create app package and deploy on your Hololens 2: [Running on HoloLens 2](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples#running-on-hololens-2).

To solve your issue that unsmooth scene objects rendering experience, you can create a **ARM64** **Release** package instead of **Debug** one. Then you will find the issue will disappear and rendering will be smooth. The main reason is the debug mode build will have additional performance consumption. See the seventh point in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/legacy-xr-support#manual-setup-without-mrtk).

[image]

Verified on HoloLens 2 with the latest 21H1 OS (10.0.20346.1002)